# How can I make a mysql_query a true or false variable in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I am looking to have the sql_query look into the Table and tell me in a $variable if the item is in the Table or not.

Am I going about this all wrong?

```
$string = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'item'");

if ( $string == true ) {
    $roger = "Found it!";
    } else {
    $roger = "Sorry dude!";
    }

echo $roger;
```

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows()`. If `> 0` it was found, if `= 0`, not found.

Comment: `$string` will always be true as long as your query was syntactically correct,so you cannot use it to determine the size of your rowset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'item'");

if ( mysql_num_rows($resource) > 0 ) {
    $roger = "Found it!";
} else {
    $roger = "Sorry dude!";
}

echo $roger;
```

Comment: Sorry, I added exactly the same answer. Deleted mine.